# Cookies are enabled but website says they're not

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use node with Puppeteer to log in to a website but it doesn't let me navigate to the login page. Instead I am re-directed to a page that says that I need to enable cookies in my Chromium browser. When I navigate to the login page manually, I'm not re-directed and my cookies are enabled so I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Perhaps a custom data path: https://www.toptal.com/puppeteer/headless-browser-puppeteer-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved by using a different login URL.